# Designing report template in word and how to use it in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, report

i am writinig a program that in finish must export a report.
bu i dont want to uese crystal reports or any other ways in c#.
i want to design a word template of the report.
and when i press on a report button it must generate report for all persons in the database..
so, can you tell me how can i use word template in c#.
and how to make it to generate reports for all persons in the database..
THANKS..

Comment: @matti Virkkunen, if it means the accounting department doesn't need to ask IT for changes to the templates, it could save the company _piles_ of money. Or maybe @namco is awesome at Word? :)

Comment: so, do you know the answer??????????????????????

Comment: You sure that's enough question marks?

Answer (score 0):

We use [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) to perform mail merges and word document generation from .net code. You can generate a template document and then merge data into predefined fields inside that template. It's not cheap but once you get to grips with it it's very powerful.